# Determine concurrency count for Resilience4j bulkhead

Tags: resilience4j, bulkhead

I'd like to track the concurrency levels of my bulkhead in an application for monitoring purposes.

Is the concurrency count for a Resiliency4j bulkhead externally available?

I can keep tack of it myself with the onCallPermitted and onCallFinished event callbacks, but I would rather not have to keep track of that if it is already available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bulkhead.getMetrics](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.github.resilience4j/resilience4j-bulkhead/1.4.0/io/github/resilience4j/bulkhead/Bulkhead.html#getMetrics--) does the trick.